# How to get an activity via a view owned by this activity?

Tags: android, view, android-activity, activity-finish

I wrote a standalone custom OnClickListener class (not a member class) for my navigation bar. see codes below.

```
class MyClickHandler implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent;
    Context ctx = view.getContext();
    int id = view.getId();
    switch(id){

    case R.id.app_home_id:
        intent = new Intent(ctx, FormEngineMainApp.class);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.app_tasklist_id:
        intent = new Intent(ctx, WorkList.class);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
        break;
    //more cases...

    }

}

}
```

Each button leads to a different activity. I tend to finish current activity after calling `startActivity(intent);`, but I need the current activity instance to call `finish()`. I have no idea how to get the current activity instance. the only thing may help is the parameter `view`, but I checked out the Reference of View in Android Developers and failed to find a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't calling finish on an activity mean that you can't use the back button to get back to that activity?

Comment: `if(this instanceof YourActivityName)`

Answer (score 1):

When you call a `finish()`, the entry of that activity from the stack is removed so I believe you can never get a reference to that old activity anyway!

In your case the best part would be to call using `startActivityWithResult(..., ...)` and then depending on the `requestCode` call finish before getting the reference of the old activity.

Comment: Self-solved. I found that it's possible to cast a context to an activity by simply adding cast to the context. in this case, adding `((Activity) ctx).finish();` after `startActivity(intent);` does solve the problem. I always object to use overqualified methods. in my case, i dont need a result so I avoid to use `startActivityWithResult()`. Anyway, thanks for your answer.